# troubleshooting to upgrade Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

any suggestion to resolve that trouble?

`brew upgrade`

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
patchelf 0.10 -> 0.11
==> Upgrading patchelf 0.10 -> 0.11 
==> Downloading http://timelessname.com/elfbin/helloworld.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/felipe/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/e8943dd8577098994c9cc5eb1dc934bb5e93f97834dd65be5ea969e1d144deec--helloworld.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/archive/0.11.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/felipe/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/bbcd82d38c35bbbe19f8fc9c11c1a6a9294473a0c235cd5d295718d3108dd349--patchelf-0.11.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/patchelf/0.11 CXXFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
Last 15 lines from /home/felipe/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/patchelf/01.configure:
2020-08-29 21:18:19 -0400

./configure
--prefix=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/patchelf/0.11
CXXFLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
--disable-debug
--disable-dependency-tracking
--disable-silent-rules


READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
patchelf 0.12 https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/pull/21032
```

i'm trying to upgrade a brew but it's happening something wrong.
can you help me to fix it?

Comment: did you try reading the troublingshooting page?

Comment: there is nothing explaining about this

Comment: can you attach the `brew config` and `brew doctor` output?

Answer (score 0):

`brew config`

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.4.14
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: fa39db0192c3641ed18abf93371c31e3a220348f
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core
Core tap HEAD: a394692bb5092789dd8cf49561bf52cf61a1d228
Core tap last commit: 17 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: :1
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 12
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit skylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
Clang: N/A
Git: 2.20.1 => /bin/git
Curl: 7.64.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (buster)
Host glibc: 2.28
/usr/bin/gcc: 8.3.0
glibc: N/A
gcc: N/A
xorg: N/A

`brew doctor`

brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.